# Group by Class constructor results based on a variable value in java

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have a resultset from a query that I want to access a certain way.

I want to get a list of employees, and for each employee the different overtimes they do in a day. The resulset returns values such as:

empl_id, empl_name, overtime_day, overtime_start, overtime_end.

I want to get these results in json but I want to group them by employee id, that is, I dont want this:

```
empl_id = 125 
empl_name = Niki Smith
overtime_day = 18/7/2019
     overtime_start = 18:00
     overtime_end = 20:00 

empl_id = 125 
empl_name = Niki Smith
overtime_day = 18/7/2019
     overtime_start = 21:00
     overtime_end = 22:00
```

I want something like this:

```
empl_id = 125 
empl_name = Niki Smith
overtime_day = 18/7/2019
     overtime_start = 18:00
     overtime_end = 20:00 

     overtime_start = 21:00
     overtime_end = 22:00
```

I have a class Employee and a constructor

```
public Employee(String empl_id , String empl_name, String overtime_day,
            ArrayList<Overtime> overtimes)
```

and a class Overtime with String variables and getters / setters for overtime_start and overtime_end

I don't have much experience with handling sets or maps and such so I would appreciate any ideas on how to structure my resultset like this. Thank you.

Comment: how are you retrieving the data ? Can you share your db design.

Comment: Not clear what you want, Do you need DTO structure for your JSON ?

Comment: I have an sql query: ResultSet= Stmt.executeQuery("select empl_id, empl_name, overtime_day, overtime_start, overtime_end from tableA"); and I want to add the data in different strings.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are retrieving your data as a resultSet this means you are retreiving a relational model, so it is expected to get a row for each entry of the overtime, the representation you are looking for unfortunately cannot be done in relational models because eventually you are getting records of data and not objects.

To solve your problem you have two options

1. ORM models, instead of retrieving your data in a resultset , you can map your relational model to java model using ORM frameworks like hibernate, and have your java model represetn the desired output ( employee object with list of overtime entries).
2. Handle it manually, once you retrieve your data from the result set create a map with key id of employee and value object representing your output and each time your retrieve a record check the employee id in the map, if it does not exist add a new object , if it exists add the overtime entry to list in employee object.
   Something like this:

   ```
   Map<String, String> employeeMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

   //Iterate over result set with rs
   while (rs.next()) { 
   {
        OverTime entry = new OverTime(rs.getString("start"), 
        rs.getString("end"));
        String id = rs.getString("id");
        if(!employeeMap.containsKey(id) {
           employeeMap.put(id, new Employee(id));
         }
       employeeMap.get(id).getOverTimeList.add(entry); 
   }
   ```

Comment: i am trying to do the 2nd suggestion, and I dont know how to handle it

Answer (score 0):

You can create a map : `Map<String, Employee> map` //Take emp_id has key for map

Loop over the result Set, check if emp_id is present in map or not. If it is present, retrieve the Employee object. Add overtime details in ArrayList overtimes. and put it back to the map.

At last you can retrieve all employee by `map.values()`